# Access class or singleton from other activities

Tags: java, android, sockets, singleton

So I have network socket class that should be handling my socket connection that i want running when my app is running. Problem is I dont know how to reference the class other than just starting a new one.

To start a new one I would do:

```
Networker network = null;
try {
    network = new Networker(SERVER_IP, SERVERPORT);
    new Thread(network).start();
```

Then i could do:(from the same activity I just did the above in)

```
 network.send("helloworld");
```

How can i do a network.send in any class without making a whole new socket connection?

Edit:
Here is my Networker Class:

```
public class Networker implements Runnable, Closeable {
    private final Socket clientSocket;
    private final PrintWriter out;
    private final BufferedReader in;
    private volatile boolean closed = false;

    public Networker(String hostname, int port) throws IOException {
        clientSocket = new Socket(hostname, port);
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            for(String fromServer; (fromServer = in.readLine()) != null;)
                System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            if (!closed)
                Log.i("logging", "error")   ;
        }
    }

    public void send(String line) {
        out.println(line);
    }

    public void close() {
        closed = true;
        try { clientSocket.close(); } catch (IOException ignored) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Singleton will be the best option. So that you can access it from any where in your application.

Comment: i guess thats what im asking how to do or what it would look like.

Comment: I am not sure is this proper implementation in socket programming!!. For singleton object, Create  a method like `public Networker getInstance(){ lazzy intialize object here and return}` . this method should create `Networker object`, if it is null. Instead of calling constructor call this method.

Comment: Do you want to keep the connection always open ?